# Why bind function stop working in this case for NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, bind

Why bind function stops working for the following code?

```
function exitHandler(options, err) {
  console.log('exit');
  if (options.cleanup) console.log('clean');
  if (err) console.log(err.stack);
  if (options.exit) process.exit();
}

//do something when app is closing
//process.on('exit', exitHandler.bind(null,{cleanup:true})); process.exit()

// or
process.on('exit', function() {
  exitHandler.bind(null,{cleanup:true})
});
```

If I un-comment the `process.on('exit', exitHandler.bind...` line, it'd work fine.

Comment: `.bind` doesn't actually call the function (that would be... `.call`), it just binds it, setting `this` appropriately. In the commented case you're passing the bound function *as the callback*; in the second case you're wrapping it in another anonymous function but never calling the bound function. Why not just stick with the commented version? Or, given that you don't actually *use* `this` in `exitHandler` (and explicitly set it to `null` instead), don't bind it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because the bind creates a new function so in your second example it does not actually fire the function. In the first case it does get fired.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, to the apparently noob like me! I can't accept the answer until 6 minutes later... BTW, to whoever wondering "_Why not just stick with the commented version?_", because I'm adding more code, obviously, it was removed from OP for less distraction.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is `bind` and not `call` what you want:

```
  function exitHandler(options, err) {
    console.log('exit');
    if (options.cleanup) console.log('clean');
    if (err) console.log(err.stack);
    if (options.exit) process.exit();
  }

  process.on('exit', function() {
    exitHandler.call(null,{cleanup:true})
  });
```

**EDIT:**

If you are not using the context (`this`) you could call the function normally:

```
exitHandler({cleanup:true});
```

Comment: Or just `exitHandler({cleanup:true})` since the `this` arg isn't used anyway.

Comment: @doodlemeister, you're right, however, I'm trying to stay as close to what the OP has as long as is technically correct

Comment: @doodlemeister, not true. That's the first thing I tried, and I got `if (options.cleanup)... TypeError: Cannot read property 'cleanup' of null`. Anyone knows why?

Comment: @xpt sounds like you were doing `exitHandler(null, { cleanup: true })` ?